# Телефонограма/лист/посилка прийшла чи прибула?

Tags: вживання-слів

Телефонограма/лист/посилка прийшла чи прибула? В СМС з пошти посилка "прибула", а [Cловник української мови](http://sum.in.ua/s/Posylka) не вказав прикладу з цими словами.

Comment: Може і [приходити](http://sum.in.ua/s/prykhodyty) («прийшла»), і [прибувати](http://sum.in.ua/s/prybuvaty) («прибула»), і [надходити](http://sum.in.ua/s/nadkhodyty) («надійшла» (і навіть бувати доставленою чи доставлятися). Варто дивитися за дієсловами, а не лише за іменниками. А [тут](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/dictua/) у багатьох слів можна подивитися синоніми.

Answer (score 1):

#### 1. [Приходити](http://ukrlit.org/slovnyk/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8)

> 3. тільки 3 ос. Доставлятися до місця призначення за вказаною адресою; **надходити**.

Л. П. Косач (Українка), лист ["До М. М. Коцюбинського"](http://%D0%94%D0%BE%20%D0%9C.%20%D0%9C.%20%D0%9A%D0%BE%D1%86%D1%8E%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE):

> Тепер я оце від двох тижнів пробуваю в гостині у п. Ольги
>   Кобилянської, отже, ми зважили послати наші вкладки літературні вкупі,
>   та ще взяли три вірша від п. Маковея, що теж тут в Чернівцях мешкає.
>   Сподіваємось, що наша посилка **прийде** ще не занадто пізно.

#### 2. [Надходити](http://ukrlit.org/slovnyk/%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8)

> 3. Приходити на місце призначення, доставлятися куди-небудь (про щось відправлене, послане і т. ін.).

З [листів Бориса Антоненка-Давидовича](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=PHRgAAAAMAAJ&q=%22%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%96%D0%B9%D1%88%D0%BB%D0%B0%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0%22&dq=%22%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%96%D0%B9%D1%88%D0%BB%D0%B0%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0%22&hl=uk&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiS9_ig0__ZAhUG2ywKHdVVCzQ4ChDoAQg_MAY):

> Насамперед, хочу повідомити Вас, що нарешті надійшла посилка, яку Ви
>   надіслали ще в грудні.

#### 3. [Прибувати](http://ukrlit.org/slovnyk/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8)

> 3. Доставлятися на місце призначення; надходити куди-небудь (про речі). //  **Надходити** за адресою (про поштові відправлення).

Авторів рівня пані Косач чи Антоненка-Давидовича тут знайти не можу. Цитата з Коцюбинського, що наведена у словнику, не має зв’язки "прибувати"+"посилка", натомість там є "відповідь"+"прибувати", тож не можу вважати це за приклад.

### Обережний висновок:

За словником всі ці слова можна використовувати у значення надходження листа/посилки на пошту/за адресою, але я б не зловживав словом "прибувати".